# v-slot can only be used on components or <template> tag

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

New to using Vue & nuxt, but I am getting an error that: `v-slot` can only be used on components or `<template>` tag.

Any advice on what to do, I googled it, looked at Nuxt documentation, and I'm a little lost.
Any advice would be appreciated.

```html
<section class="banner"></section>
<body {background-color: #000000;} scroll="no" style="overflow: hidden"></body>                 
  <div class="First"> 
    <p style="color:#EB7051;">SourceSweep</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your `background-color` style is not inside any attribute.  Move it into the existing `style` attribute:

```
<body scroll="no" style="overflow: hidden; background-color: #000000;"></body>
```

The reason you got this particular error message is because when `#` is used as an attribute, it is shorthand for `v-slot` targeting, and this is what the compiler thought you intended to do because of the floating hash mark.  (Those `v-slot` or `#` directives have to be on the `<template>` tag.)